# Forensics: electrostatic detection circuit for lifting "indentations" from documents

Tags: static, sensitivity, field-strength

[Wikipedia explains that an EDD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_detection_device):

> ...is a specialized piece of equipment [used to] reveal indentations
>   or impressions in paper which may otherwise go unnoticed. The
>   electro-physical basis whereby an EDD actually works is [...] a
>   surface charge effect created by paper-to-paper friction specifically
>   in the area where a writing instrument is pressed down into the
>   top-most sheet of paper

It involves plastic film, high voltages, messy toner, and by the sounds of it, quite a bit of practice.

Is it still done this way today? Or is it now done electronically? How easy would it be to make a circuit with the sensitivity to detect variations in the electric field made on paper from writing?

(I want to prove that my wife used my favourite notepad, but don't want to get toner over her new carpet).

Comment: I'd go with the old method of using a soft pencil (4B or 6B)  gently applied at a shallow angle over the surface of the paper, but before that I'd ask myself - "Do I **really** want a stupid argument with my wife over a sheet of paper?"

Comment: I'd use fingerprints for that.

Comment: A bright light (e.g., LED flashlight) held at a shallow angle can also reveal a lot. But I agree with @JImDearden about the argument. Just plan on buying more notepads and let it go.

Comment: The glancing illumination is a good idea.  This is how optical mice work and they have been hacked in the past to go into debug modes where they work as cameras and you can see the paper texture.  It might be a way to go if you want to hack a mouse.

Comment: The notepad thing was a joke :) and the Wikipedia article points out that physically detectable indentations should first be checked for using a bright light at an angle (to see shadows), and that the electrostatic method is for harder problems (that a pencil wouldn't work for. Nice idea though). A UK govt forensic agency sold off their EDD machines circa 2012 and was wondering if it's due to new technology

Comment: I suspect it is due to new technology, but not in the detection: hardly anyone keeps paper notes any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, to answer the actual question, a couple of thoughts pop to mind. First of all, to correct a misconception, the EDD process measures the charge left on the film after it has been in contact with the paper "for a few minutes". The paper itself does not retain a charge.

The [Versatec printer](http://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/X163.83A) was an early electrostatic printer/plotter that used an array of "nibs" to write an electric charge pattern directly onto paper, which was then developed using toner suspended in liquid (rather messy, unfortunately). The same nib array could conceivably be used to sense electrostatic patterns on plastic films.